# ng-zorro cascader lazy load data, nzLoadData function got this=undefined

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I want to lazy load data for cacader. But failed because in the load function this=undefined. The function is defined in component, and other functions in the component working well.
Please help, thanks.

```html
<nz-cascader  
  \[nzLoadData\]\="loadCityBuildingData"  
  \[(ngModel)\]\="selectedLocation"  
  (ngModelChange)\="onNewLocationModalChanges($event)"  
\> </nz-cascader>
```

```js
loadCityBuildingData(node: NzCascaderOption, index: number): PromiseLike<void\> {  
  console.log(this);  

 return new Promise(resolve => {  
    if (index < 0) {  
      this.cityService.getCities().subscribe(item => {  
        const cities = \[\];  
  item.forEach(city => {  
          cities.push({value: city.id, label: city.name});  
  });  
  node.children \= cities;  
  resolve();  
  });  
  } else if (index === 0) {  
      this.buildingService.getBuildingsByCityId(node.value).subscribe(item => {  
        const buildings = \[\];  
  item.forEach(building => {  
          buildings.push({value: building.id, label: building.name, isLeaf: true});  
  });  
  node.children \= buildings;  
  resolve();  
  });  
  }  
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My name's Wendell and I am the author of the component. ;)

This is a frequestly asked question. The reason is that:

1. When you pass `loadCityBuildingData` to `nzLoadData`, `loadCityBuildData` becomes a property of `NzCascaderComponent`.
2. When the cascader calls this method (by calling `nzLoadData` actually), `this` in `loadCityBuildingData` is bound to nothing.
3. So you have to bind `this` in `loadCityBuildingData` before you pass it.

   1. You could use arrow function.
   2. You could use `Function.bind`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I found that works for me is to define your function like following :

```js
loadCityBuildingData = (node: NzCascaderOption, index: number): PromiseLike<void> => {
    ...your code 
}
```